# enabling gui in Vagrantfile settings

Tags: vagrant

I've tried using `configure.vm.boot_mode = :gui` in Vegrantfile, but got this error: `The following settings shouldn't exist: boot_mode`

the way I fixed it now is by using vendor configuration (virtualbox):

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.gui = true
end
```

but I would like to avoid vendor-specific anything when not necessary. what vendor-agnostic alternative is there to this? is there a replacement to `boot_mode`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`vm.boot_mode` is gone with Vagrant 1.1, but you can still use it if you enclose it in a *V1 configuration block*:

```
Vagrant.configure("1") do |config|
  config.vm.boot_mode = :gui
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # V2 Config...
end
```

Comment: thank you! I'm just starting with vagrant and I forgot to [rtfm](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/version.html) I guess.

Comment: Good to know that we can still use V1 configure in the Vagrantfile.